# Rails 3, has_many :through and :polymorphic - Should I need to do this?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through, has-many-polymorphs

Ok so here goes. I don't know if I'm over complicating things or if I'm just still so new to Rails that I don't understand the basics. What I want in sudo code is this:

```
User
has_many projects as owner through relationship
has_many projects as contributor through relationship
has_many projects as follower through relationship

Project
has_one user as owner through relationship
has_many users as followers through relationship
has_many users as contributors through relationship

Relationship
belongs_to user
belongs_to project
```

Then I'm wanting to have the following magical things:

```
owner = Project.owner
followers = Project.followers
contributors = Project.contributors

projects = User.projects
myprojects = User.projects... (now I'm really not sure)
followedProjects = ...
contributingProjects = ...
```

So in writing that down I can see that there is another gap in my understanding of this model. The users can have the role of owner, follower or contributor or any combination of all three.

In terms of real code I have added here what I think is the relevant parts:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_project_relationships, :as => :relateable, :class_name => "UserProjectRelationship"
  has_many :projects, :as => :owner, :through => :relateable, :class_name => "Project", :source_type => :owner
  has_many :projects, :as => :follower, :through => :relateable, :class_name => "Project", :source_type => :follower
  has_many :projects, :as => :contributor, :through => :relateable, :class_name => "Project", :source_type => :contributor
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_project_relationships, :as => :relateable, :class_name => "UserProjectRelationship"
  has_one :user, :as => :owner, :through => :relateable, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :users, :as => :followers, :through => :relateable, :source_type => :follower, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :users, :as => :contributors, :through => :relateable, :source_type => :contributor, :class_name => "User"
end

class UserProjectRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project, :polymorphic => true
end
```

The migration for the relationships model is:

```rb
class CreateUserProjectRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :user_project_relationships do |t|
      t.integer :relateable_id
      t.string :relateable_type
      t.integer :project_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :user_project_relationships, [:relateable_id, :relateable_type], :name => :relateable
    add_index :user_project_relationships, :project_id
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :user_project_relationships
  end
end
```

Currently I get errors for things like project.users `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :relateable in model Project`

I feel like I'm too in the wilderness here to really get what I want, and maybe relying on magical rails to do more than it does. Any guidance on the best path would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails can do alot, but I think instead you're trying to make the Relationship model do too much.  Each of those are a different kind of relationship, so I think try to keep them so.

Split that up into separate join models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :owned_projects, :class_name => "Project", :foreign_key => :owner_id

  has_many :projects_followers
  has_many :followed_projects, :class_name => "Project", :through => :projects_followers

  has_many :projects_contributors
  has_many :contributed_projects, :class_name => "Project", :through => :projects_contributors

end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner

  has_many :projects_followers
  has_many :followers, :class_name => "User", :through => :projects_followers


  has_many :projects_contributors, :foreign_key => :contributor_id
  has_many :contributors, :class_name => "User", :through => :projects_contributors

end

class ProjectsFollowers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class ProjectsContributors < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Should be a lot closer to what you want. You can then indeed do

```
project.owner
project.followers
project.contributors
```

and

```
user.owned_projects
user.followed_projects
user.contributed_projects
```

That should either work, or get you pretty close.

I think your mixup came from trying to make a polymorphic relationship, which I don't think is desireable here. AFAI grok, the use case for polymorphic relationships is when you want 1 Model to be related to Any number of other models *in the same way*. That's not the case here, as you have 2 models with 3 different types of relationships between them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that sounds like what I want but I guess it feels like duplication at a database level. I come from years of PHP/MySQL work where I would use one single join table to handle the relationship from both sides. As in: Users -- Users2Projects -- Projects. Is there any risk with the two relationships becoming orphaned? Is this down to the app to enforce? I'm adding two relationships here to serve each side of the many-to-many. What if one gets removed without the other, you end up not following a project but still seen as a follower from the project side.

Comment: Hey again. Having trouble implementing this and testing it does what I expect. Getting this error when I try to associate a user to follow a project:
`project.project_followers << user
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ProjectFollower(#2155362360) expected, got User(#2158321740)`

Comment: 1) You're right about the orphaning - it's handled by Rails as well- you want to add :dependent => :destroy keys to projects_followers and projects_contributors.

2) projects_followers and projects_contributors are there for completeness in the has_many_through relationship, and they are useful if you need to add extra keys to these relationships (how long has someone been a contributor? how many contributions have they made? etc.), but you can also frequently ignore them.  The reason you are getting that error is you should go to the followers association directly:  project.followers << user